# Derby Embedded Driver Error XBM02 Please ensure your classpath includes the correct Derby software

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, derby, hana

I am building a JavaEE application with Spring and I am trying to connect it with the DerbyEmbeddedDriver. This application will be used on SAP HANA Cloud Platform trial, so I am using their version of Tomcat 8.

Tomcat 8 can be found at: https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/

SAP HCP: https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com/

The error occurs when I start the Tomcat server. This is what I see:

> ```
> Caused by: ERROR XJ041: Failed to create database 'memory:DemoDB', see the next exception for details.
>   at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
>   ... 113 more
> Caused by: ERROR XBM02: Startup failed due to missing functionality for org.apache.derby.iapi.types.DataValueFactory. Please ensure your classpath includes the correct Derby software.
>   at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.missingImplementation(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
>   ... 110 more
> ```

Which regards to the error, I am using Maven and this is my Derby dependency config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.13.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So I assume maven should add this to the Maven Dependencies lib, hence I don't need to add explicitly this on the Classpath, right?

And regarding the creation of the Data Source object. This Tomcat server has a config file under Servers//config_master/connection_data/connection.properties that contains:

```
#----------------------------------------
# Connection parameters for a local Derby database
# DB and tables are created automatically (if missing)
#----------------------------------------
javax.persistence.jdbc.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:derby:memory:DemoDB;create=true
javax.persistence.jdbc.user=demo
javax.persistence.jdbc.password=demo
eclipselink.target-database=Derby

#----------------------------------------
# Connection parameters MaxDB
#----------------------------------------
#javax.persistence.jdbc.driver=com.sap.dbtech.jdbc.DriverSapDB
#javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:sapdb://<host>/DEMO
#javax.persistence.jdbc.user=demo
#javax.persistence.jdbc.password=demo
#eclipselink.target-database=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MaxDBPlatform
```

This is consumed by the Server and it will create a new Data Source and inject it on the context based on the name defined, so when I want to get it on the Application all I do is this:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/memory/DemoDB");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Can you point anything that I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue... The problem was that the derby dependency was listed twice on the pom.xml as a test dependency...

This pom.xml file was reused from another project and skipped this when sanitizing it.